# Adding numbers in a list python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

[image: photo:]

I have created a loop to print the above values but I need to add them and find the average. can someone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please copy and paste your code directly into the post 
instead of linking to, or inserting an image of it. To learn more about formatting please read: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Before the loop, `gather = []`; inside the loop `gather.append(R)`; after the loop, `print(sum(gather)/len(gather))`.  I would include the code in an answer if you had cut-and-pasted it instead of using an image.

Comment: Initiate an empty list. mylist = [] Replace your print statement with mylist.append(R)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> su = 0
>>> N = 100
>>> m = 2
>>> x = 0
>>> mean = lambda data: sum(data)/len(data)
>>> mean([nx.degree_assortativity_coefficient(
>>>       nx.barabasi_albert_graph(N,m)) for i in range(0,10)])
```